# Does a wifi repeater mimic the defects of a poorly performing wifi router or broadcast a better wifi signal?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Are wifi repeaters designed to duplicate the original signal at a different location, inheriting any flaws from wifi routers poor positioning and badly arranged antenna, or do they give a 'pure' version of the signal?
What is the correct theoretical answer?

Comment: Its digital data, there is no pure version. It either works or it doesn't.

Comment: A repeater depending on design may reduce signal in half (traffic back and forth) and usually will be no better than base. Now I have a Ubiquiti Access Point connected by Ethernet to the main router and it is excellent for wireless speed

Comment: If the signal going *into* a repeater is bad, there is no mechanism to improve the quality. A device could be designed to ask for repetition of packets, and improve accuracy through statistical analysis of the data, but that *drastically* slows speed and is reserved for such tasks as deep-space communications. https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/

Comment: Antenna placement or ability does not change the signal that is broadcast. It DOES impact how that signal propagates. A repeater can only repeat the signal it receives. The effect is to make the network accessible further away, but at a significant cost to speed and throughput. They do not improve the quality of the signal they are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the repeater is when the distance from an emitter and a destination is too high, then the repeater - placed closer to the emitter - get the 0 and 1 correctly and regenerate them with full power. If the repeater is also closer to the destination the transmition has more chance to be good.

However, if the reapeter has poor positioning or badly arranged antenna, there is no reason it will be better than a router with similar characteristics.